# GitHub Deployment to Azure

Tags: angularjs, git, azure, github

I've tried to upload my Angular2 project from GitHub to Azure but I get the following error when I open the Azure page:

`You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

The GitHub deploy to Azure worked fine, no problem. Does anybody know the reason why I still get this error message?

Here's [my GitHub project](https://github.com/Fodrigoal/Assignment2Angular2)

Here's [my Azure website](http://assignment2angular.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Try - http://assignment2angular.azurewebsites.net/src/

Comment: @radu-matei it keeps loading forever

Only shows "Loading..." in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You are using Azure Web App and Azure uses IIS to host your application. So, basically, you no longer need to handle your Angular2 project with the Node.js script.

Please try to delete your `server.js` file from `/wwwroot` folder, and also remove the following content in `web.config` file.

```
<handlers>
    <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>
```